# How to put object on detected surface?

Tags: 8thwall-xr

How can i put object on detected surface in 8th wall AR.
I couldn't get detected surfaces position.
It only gives rotation and mesh etc but not position.
Can u please describe me the process to put object on detected sufaces.
I am using 8th wall AR sdk.

Answer (score 0):

There is a helper script, `XRSurfaceController` provided in the 8th Wall XR Unity package. This script can be used to know when surfaces have been detected, and to place objects on them accordingly.

Typically what you'd do is is create a `Plane` type game object in your scene and attach the `XRSurfaceController` script to that object to create a surface in your application. Then, you'd add any objects you'd like to be placed onto your surface as children of the `Plane` game object.

More information and examples on `XRSurfaceController` can be found on the 8th Wall documentation site: https://docs.8thwall.com/#xrsurfacecontroller